# Microsoft edge doesn't support embed tag?

Tags: html, embed, microsoft-edge

I testing this code that works in every browser aside of Microsoft Edge.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test embed</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <embed autoplay = 'false' type = 'video/mp4' src = 'http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4' />
    </body>
</html>
```

However I can't find any info about this tag support by Edge. Maybe we need to do something else to make `embed` work in Edge?

Ms Edge simply shows blank page.

I am not planning to use `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<embed> is not currently supported in Microsoft Edge and there is no target implementation for <embed> in sight as of right now.

To be Microsoft Edge compatible you need to move to the HTML5 Video standard.  Your video renders fine using the following HTML block below.  Click on the cool little 'run code snippet' thing to see.

Some additional resources to read up on.

w3schools on html5 video tags - http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_video.asp

w3schools audio/video dom ref - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Some resource to supply feedback on Microsoft Edge and suggest features.

- Bugs for Edge and IE - https://connect.microsoft.com/ie/feedback
- Developer Feedback Home -
  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer
- Developer Feedback Twitter - https://www.twitter.com/msedgedev
- Feature Suggestions -
  https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/category/18985-web-browsing

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa....

```html
    <div>
        <strong>baboo from web</strong> <br />
        <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
           <source src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video> 
</div>
```